# WebStorm Git Log Tab: How to tell to which branch does a commit belong to?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In our team we are working with feature branches and environment branches commit policy.
I am using WebStorm as IDE.

Since our branching strategy involves working with many branches and creates a broad git log, it is often difficult to tell, to which branch(es) es commit belongs log.

See here a typical snapshot of our Git Log:
[image]

Selecting a specific commit, how can I tell, to which branch this commit was added to?
Of course I know that a commit can belong to several branches. In addition, it would be of interest, which is the most recent branch, this change was committed to.

Context menu apparently does not offer such information:

[image: Git Log Content Menu]

Even on the right pane, one can only see, to which branches this commit eventually was added to, but it's also not possible to see the immediate branch, this commit was added to:

[image]

Can you help on this topic?

Comment: How do you define "most recent branch"? Branches only have a name and a ref to which they point, nothing else (no metadata with time). What is "the immediate branch a commit was added to"? Commits are not added to branches, commits are standalone and point to their parent(s). Branches reference commits. If you commit and then create a new branch, there is no way to find out if the new branch or the original branch is the "branch of the commit" – both are. There simply is now way. "In 54 branches" is the only answer Git can give you

Answer (score 0):

To add to @knittl answers, you can "track" the movement of the commit through branches by going over the list from top to bottom (the first branch being where the commit originated from)